# הקדוש ברוך הוא אנחנו אוהבים אותך ‎— or אותו?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, song-poetry

There is a popular song some of whose lyrics are "הקדוש ברוך הוא אנחנו אוהבים אותך". Does anyone have a source — besides some recent lyricist — for these words precisely, or a source for any instance of "הקדוש ברוך הוא" (preferably, or its Aramaic counterpart "קודשא בריך הוא") being used with a second- (or first-) person pronoun (or verb)? All the examples of "הקדוש ברוך הוא" (or "קודשא בריך הוא") that I can think of use third-person pronouns and verbs.

Comment: According to [some Web page](http://www.breslev.co.il/articles/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9A/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%91.aspx?id=9844&language=hebrew), the lyrics are of unknown [and seemingly recent] authorship, popularized in [Uman](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10267). I have no idea whether that's correct, though.

Comment: R. Yehoshua Mondshine, in a footnote to an essay on the Baal Hatanya's siddur [published in Hasiddur (ed. R. Gedaliah Oberlander, Monsey: Heichal Menachem, 2003), p. 109], states flatly that "the popular slogan, 'Hakadosh baruch hu, we love You' did not come from a Jewish source, as is well known." However, he doesn't give any further details.

Comment: @Alex, that's an answer (in the negative) to my question, "Does anyone have a source — besides some recent lyricist — for these words precisely", and (IMO) worth posting as one.

Comment: Just pointing out that switching from third to second person in reference to God in not unheard of (e.g. "לַיהוָה הַיְשׁוּעָה עַל עַמְּךָ בִרְכָתֶךָ סֶּלָה")

Answer (score 2):

There is no "source" for this phrase. These are the words of a Breslev chasid that he spontaneously yelled after Tashlich in Uman about 10 years ago.

"Source": [This article](http://www.uman.co.il/viewart.asp?artID=78)

Comment: @DoubleAA link works for me

Comment: @ShmuelBrin For me it's just giving me lots of funny looking characters instead of Hebrew letters. Maybe it's my browser? That would be odd because the Hebrew in the google cache renders just fine. Well, if it's just my issue then feel free to edit in the original link.

Comment: @DoubleAA try changing encoding settings.

Comment: @DoubleAA The encoding is "Hebrew (Windows-1255)" and not UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The [Shefa Chaim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36035&pgnum=260) brings a story regarding the Baal Shem Tov where he visited a shepard who said רבש״ע אני כל כך אוהב אותך.

Comment: But I was asking specifically about הקדוש ברוך הוא.

Comment: to me it seamed that you were asking about the Otcha or Oto.

Comment: Yes, but specifically as it refers back to _Hashem_ as referred to by the term הקדוש ברוך הוא (or קודשא בריך הוא).