# Change from 2nd to 3rd Person in Yehi Ratzon

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk

As part of putting on my tefillin in the morning, I say a prayer (found on page 13 of my Siddur Tefilla Hashalem, by A. Greenwald, which I can't find online) beginning with "L'shem Yichud". The text at the end reads as follow:
ויהי רצון מלפניך...שתהא חשובה מצות הנחת תפילין **לפני הקדוש ברוך הוא**...

(I added the bold).

The section of the prayer which begins in the second person ("may it be thy will") immediately goes into third person (referring to HKB"H and not simply "before you", lifanecha).

Why would this prayer make such a shift?

The parallel prayer in the siddur Rinat Yisrael (as seen [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34229&st=&pgnum=19)) has different language to stay in the second person but I don't know if my Greenwald siddur predates the 1970 publication of the Rinat. Which is the "original" version and why would the text ever switch persons?

Comment: similar issue https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60271/759

Comment: see also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12781

Comment: rosends, this is a fairly common thing in Hebrew prayers. Consider the following: _Baruch atah Hashem_ (Blessed are You, L-rd) _Asher kid'shanu b'mitzvotav_ (who has sanctified us with His commandments). A clear change in person here in the most common beginning for brachot!

Comment: @ezra see link in 1st comment. That's pretty much the same idea in all brachot.